# Apply a function across all combinations of variables and store the plot in a list where we can plot all (or part) of the ggplot lists

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data (iris dataset) and I also have a plotting function called `decisionplot`. My question is how can I apply the `decisionplot` function (which outputs a `ggplot` plot) to all combinations of variables in my data. That is, in the iris data set we have;

```
"Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

I want to apply the function `decisionplot` to the following combinations:

```
"Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"
"Sepal.Length" "Petal.Length"
"Sepal.Length" "Petal.Width"

"Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length"
"Sepal.Width" "Petal.Width"

"Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Store these plot combinations in a list where I can plot on a grid the different outputs.

The data and the `decisionplot` function is the following:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(Species = +(Species == "virginica"))


decisionplot <- function(model, data, class = NULL, model_type = "NA", predict_type = "class",
                         resolution = 300, main, showgrid = TRUE, ...) {

  if(!is.null(class)){
    cl <- data[,class]
  }
  else{
    cl <- 1
  }

  k <- length(unique(cl))



  # make grid
  r <- sapply(data[,1:2], range, na.rm = TRUE)
  xs <- seq(r[1,1], r[2,1], length.out = resolution)
  ys <- seq(r[1,2], r[2,2], length.out = resolution)
  g <- cbind(rep(xs, each=resolution), rep(ys, time = resolution))
  colnames(g) <- colnames(r)
  g <- as.data.frame(g)

  ### guess how to get class labels from predict
  ### (unfortunately not very consistent between models)
  if(model_type == "xgboost"){
    message(paste0("Running Model ", model_type))
    p <- predict(object = model, newdata = xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(g)), type = predict_type)
    #p <- ifelse(p > tail(sort(p),1000)[1000], "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt")
    p <- ifelse(p > 0.50, "Bankrupt", "Non-Bankrupt")
  }
  else {
    message(paste0("Running Model ", model_type))
    p <- predict(model, g, type = predict_type)
  }
  if(is.list(p)) p <- p$class
  if(is.logical(p)) p <- ifelse(p == TRUE, "Non-Bankrupt", "Bankrupt")
  p <- as.factor(p)

  plot_data <- cbind(g, p) %>% 
    setNames(c("X1", "X2", "Y")) %>% 
    mutate(class_num = case_when(
      Y == "Non-Bankrupt" ~ 1,
      Y == "Bankrupt" ~ 2
    ))
  ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = X1, y = X2, colour = Y),
               data = plot_data) +
    geom_contour(aes(x = X1, y = X2, z = class_num),
                 bins = 2,
                 data = plot_data, size = 0.001) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Xvar1, y = Xvar2, color = factor(Yvar)),
               size = 3,
               data = data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Xvar1, y = Xvar2),
               size = 3,
               shape = 1,
               #alpha = 0.2,
               data = data) +
    labs(title = paste(main),
         x = var1_to_plot,
         y = var2_to_plot)

}
```

I then set my variable I want to put through the function and create my `boundary_data`:

```
var1_to_plot = "Sepal.Length"
var2_to_plot = "Sepal.Width"

boundary_data <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(rlang::eval_tidy(var1_to_plot), rlang::eval_tidy(var2_to_plot), Species) %>% 
  mutate(Species = factor(Species)) %>% 
  setNames(c("Xvar1", "Xvar2", "Yvar")) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

I finally create my logistic model and run the `decisionplot` function.

```
model <- glm(Yvar ~., data = boundary_data, family = binomial(link='logit'))
class(model) <- c("lr", class(model))
predict.lr <- function(object, newdata, ...)
  predict.glm(object, newdata, type = "response") > .5
decisionplot(model, boundary_data, predict_type = "response", class = "Yvar", model_type = "Logistic", main = "Logistic Regression")
```

This gives me:

[image]

However I want to make it such that this will be one of all the combinations of the variables (since here it just consideres `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.Length`).

How can I plot on a grid the different `ggplot` variable combinations? Or store the plots as a list?

**EDIT**

What I currently have is the following - Which gives me 12 lists of different combinations. Each list has 2 further lists a data set and a logistic model.

```
var_combos <- expand.grid(colnames(df[,1:4]), colnames(df[,1:4])) %>% 
  filter(!Var1 == Var2)


iter_function = function(dat, V1, V2, Y){
  data = dat %>% 
    select(rlang::eval_tidy(V1), rlang::eval_tidy(V2), Y) %>% 
    mutate(Y = factor(rlang::eval_tidy(Y)))

  # Logistic Model
  model = glm(rlang::eval_tidy(Y) ~ ., data = data, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
  class(model) <- c("lr", class(model))
  predict.lr <- function(object, newdata, ...){
    predict.glm(object, newdata, type = "response") > .5
  }
  return(list(data, model))
}

boundary_lists <- map2(
  .x = var_combos$Var1,
  .y = var_combos$Var2,
  ~iter_function(dat = df, V1 = .x, V2 = .y, Y = df$Species)
)
```

Now I want to apply each of these lists to the `decisionplot` function. I keep getting `. not found`.

```
map2(
  .x = .[[1]],
  .y = .[[2]],
  ~decisionplot(model = .x, data = .y, predict_type = "response", class = "Species", model_type = "Logistic", main = "Logistic Regression")
)
```

How can I map the funtion of list of lists? (I realise I am not giving it the `boundary_lists` list created from the `iter_function()`)

Comment: I would generate all pairwise combinations using `gtools::combinations`, and then iterate over all combinations using `purrr::pmap` to apply your function and generate the plot. This will give you a list of plots you can use as input to a function such as `cowplot::plot_grid`.

Comment: @rpolicastro Or the list of plots can also be used very easily with in `patchwork::wrap_plots`

Comment: I have all the different combinations using `var_combos <- expand.grid(colnames(df[,1:4]), colnames(df[,1:4])) %>% 
  filter(!Var1 == Var2)` - I am just thinking how best to extract each row and `pmap` each combination to construct a list of new data frames which will be a list of `boundary_data` data frames.

Comment: I almost have it (I have added an EDIT).  I now just need to know how to map the first and second elements of a list using `map2()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to make use of nested data, combined with the `purrr::map` functions. This way, you can keep everything in one data frame and don't have to work with lists of lists. See https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html for a primer on working with nested data.

First, I split up your `iter_function` in two parts: one to create the dataset, and one to create the model.

```
create_data <- function(dat, V1, V2) {
  data = dat %>% 
    select(rlang::eval_tidy(V1), rlang::eval_tidy(V2), Y = Species) %>% 
    mutate(Y = as.factor(Y))
  return(data)
}

create_model <- function(data){
  # Logistic Model
  model = glm(Y ~ ., data = data, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
  class(model) <- c("lr", class(model))
  predict.lr <- function(object, newdata, ...){
    predict.glm(object, newdata, type = "response") > .5
  }
  return(model)
}
```

Then, I can create `var_combos` similarly to your code (but I use `crossing` from `tidyr` instead of `expand.grid` since this converts to tibbles). Note that also the complete dataset is in the data frame, in the `data` column. Depending on your dataset size, this may be inefficient.

```
var_combos <- crossing(var1 = colnames(df[,1:4]),
                       var2 = colnames(df[,1:4]),
                       data = list(df)) %>% 
  filter(var1 != var2)
```

Finally, using the `map` functions, I can store the filtered data, model and plot in columns in the data frame.

```
var_combos <- var_combos %>%
  mutate(data = pmap(list(data, var1, var2), create_data),
         model = map(data, create_model),
         plot = pmap(list(model, data, var1, var2), decisionplot, 
                     predict_type = "response", class = "Y",
                     model_type = "Logistic", main = "Logistic Regression")
         )
```

Now everything is stored in the same data frame. You can then plot the contents of the `plot` column with one of the methods described in the comments above.
Note that I had to add `var1_to_plot, var2_to_plot` to the function parameters of `decisionplot` to get this to work (after `model, data`).